# Creating a parametrized module over a parametrized module

Tags: ocaml, functor

I'm trying to write a module that implements algorithms on another module that may be implemented in various ways. So my thinking was to write the first module as

```
module type Base = sig
  type t
  val f : t -> t
end
```

Then I write a second module that is parametrised over a module compatible with `Base`:

```
module type BasedOnBase = functor (B : Base) -> sig
  type b
  val g : B.t -> b
end
```

Now I'm trying to write a module that is parametrised over a module that is compatible with `BasedOnBase` and this is where I'm stuck. My naive approach doesn't work, I've tried

```
(* won't compile *)

module type Alg = functor (BoB : BasedOnBase) -> sig
  val h : BoB.b -> bool
end
```

as well as

```
(* won't compile *)

module type Alg = functor (BoB : functor (B : Base) -> BasedOnBase) -> sig
  val h : BoB.b -> bool
end
```

but both attempts cause this error:

```
[...]
Error: Unbound type constructor BoB.b
```

So I'm obviously missing something here but I can't seem to be able to get my head around the problem. How would I go about achieving what I want, probably in a completely different way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write this:

```
module type Alg = functor (BoB : BasedOnBase) -> functor (B:Base) -> sig
  type t
  val h : t -> bool
end with type t = BoB(B).b
```

With this you need to pass a module `B:Base` when instanciating a module of type `Alg`, which is not the case in your question.

Edit: or even this:

```
module type Alg =
  functor (BoB : BasedOnBase) ->
  functor (B : Base) -> sig
    val h : BoB(B).b -> bool
  end
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this. I've got a (probably silly) follow-up question now: Suppose I implement the module and want to use a function from `BoB`, as in: `module Alg = functor (BoB : BasedOnBase) -> functor (B : Base) -> struct [...] let h x = BoB(B).g x end`. This gives me a syntax error, `(BoB(B).g) x` gives me `Unbound constructor BoB`. Would you mind helping me out once again?

Comment: This would work in your case: module Alg = functor (BoB : BasedOnBase) -> functor (B : Base) -> struct module X = BoB(B);; let h x = X.g x end;;

Comment: Cheers Alex, that's exactly what I ended up doing.